# Java : running time of big file inputs

Tags: java, file, time, greedy

I'm working on a project where i have ten files and for each file i have to use a greedy algorithm 10 times . However the files have huge inputs of 1000 up to 9000 elements . The code below is about only one file with 1000 elements and I  run it 10 times . I  calculate average running time and 2 other values and it takes 15 minutes for just one file . With what changes can I  make the process faster ? 
(all code runs perfectly nothing wrong with the methods displayed)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    long[] avg1=new long[10]; //stores running time of each try in array 
    long sum=0; //stores average running time 
    int gval=0;
    int optval=0;
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
    {   
        BuyersList b = new BuyersList();
        BuyersList buyers = new BuyersList();
        buyers.readFile("src/p500x1000.txt"); //reads file and adds values to list 
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        b=buyers.greedy(500); //algorithm runs 
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();    
        avg1[i]=(end-start); //calculate running time of greedy algorithm
        sum+=avg1[i];  //add time of one try to sum
        gval=b.totalValue();
        optval=buyers.opt;  
    }


    System.out.println("m= 500 :");    // for 500 objects print the values below 
    System.out.println(" n = 1000 : avgTime = " + sum/10 + " greedy value = " + gval + " opt value = " + optval + " ");



    }
```

greedy algorithm :

```
public BuyersList greedy( int m  ) {

    if(empty())
    {
        return null;
    }
    ItemsList lista = new ItemsList(); // create list of items 
    BuyerNode current=this.first;     // node that represents first buyer 
    boolean f = true;   //suppose one subset list exists 

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)  //enter pointers of items 
    {
        lista.append(i);
    }

    BuyersList best = new BuyersList(); //create the returning buyers list 


    while(f==true)    //while one subset list of complete list  exists in the list of buyers 
    {
            current=this.maximum(this); //call maximum function to set current to maximum fraction 
            boolean flag = lista.contains(current.itemsList);   // if current's list is a subset 
            if(flag==true){
            best.append(current.id,current.value,current.itemsList); //append current to the best list 
            lista.remove(current.itemsList); //remove current's list  from ItemsList 
            this.deleteNode(current.id); // call private deletenode function to delete current from buyers
            this.nbNodes--;
          }

            else {this.deleteNode(current.id);}


        BuyerNode bnode = this.first;
        f = false;  //set f to false to exit loop if it doesn't change below 
        for(bnode=this.first;bnode!=null;bnode=bnode.next)
        {   

            if(lista.contains(bnode.itemsList))  //check if itemslist contains even one buyer subset list 
            {               

                f = true;   //one subset list exists so loop again 
            }
        }

    } 




    return best;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your BuyersList.greedy() method, its difficult to suggest any code level optimizations. But assuming your algorithm is already optimized, and assuming you are running your jvm on a multi-core machine( which most of us these days are ), your current code is definitely not using the machine's full capacity. You can try running your file processing in parallel. 
You can try something like this ( example code ) :

```
CompletableFuture<ReturnType> runAlgorithm(final String fileName){
     return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
        BuyersList b = new BuyersList();
        BuyersList buyers = new BuyersList();
        buyers.readFile(fileName); 
        b=buyers.greedy(500);
     }
}

void runAllInParallel(List<String> filenames){
    List<CompletableFuture<ReturnType>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String file : filenames){
         results.add(runAlgorithm(file));
    }
    // process results here.
}
```

Comment: I cannot use arraylists on the specific project .However  let me show you the greedy algorithm